# News are printed without titles in Get SimpleCMS with News Manager

Tags: content-management-system

I use the last version of Getsimple CMS and the last version of News Manager plugin. I don't use fancy URLs.

I made all settings in admin panel for this plugin. I included styles to screen.css.
But news are printed without titles. What's the cause? What is the basic setting to make this plugin work with minimum functionality?

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't they didn't print at all, they were printed in white, and for my template css should be another.
I added to .nm_post_title a class
color: #999;
font-size: 14px;

And all worked.